# What is lost after converting Monix `Task` to Cats `IO`?

Tags: multithreading, scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, monix

This simplified case is where my question happen at...

```
object Main extends IOApp{
 def run(args:Seq[String]): IO[ExitCode]={
    Task{...}
     .to[IO]
     .as(ExitCode.Success)
 }
}
```

Another option is `Await.result(task)`, however which sounds not quite line up with `IOApp`'s practice.

### what i know

According to this great post [Monix vs Cats Effect](https://monix.io/blog/2018/03/20/monix-vs-cats-effect.html)
I see differences between `Task` `IO` are:

- `Task` API is richer than `IO`
- `Task` is smarter and automatic about thread *scheduling fairness*
- `Task` get more cancelable options
- and more ...

### question and my opinion

What I lost after I convert `Monix` `Task` into `Cats` `IO`?

It seems to work fine, with `Task.gather` and `timeout`-- all those Task specific things.
So What I lost in conversion ?
If no, then no reason to have more than one data type created.

So given the differences is that means that I lost the *scheduling fairness* after conversing `Task` to `IO` ?

---

Well I should have verified it by myself but I don't known how to test it the fairness.

Comment: I guess you shouldn't lose anything. At the end, it should be an extra **IO** which delegates the execution to the inner **Task** - Anyways, if this is just for using `IOApp` why not use [`TaskApp`](https://monix.io/api/3.1/monix/eval/TaskApp.html) instead?

Comment: thanks, I will try TaskApp. Im using http4s which suggests IOApp.

Comment: **http4s** doesn't suggest `IOApp` in the example they use it because they use `IO` because it is already in scope.

Comment: oh you are right, i get its doc wrong

Answer (score 0):

Monix Task isn't updated for cats-effect 3, nor is it likely to ever be, so at this point it's a moot question - if you want to use the current ecosystem, you use `IO`

The monix author is a major contributor to cats-effect, and at this point there's little to no functionality present in monix task which can't be also done with IO.